# Scrolling in RelativeLayout

Tags: java, android, listview, scroll, textview

I have textview and listview in the RelativeLayout. How can I do scroll this textview when I scrolling listview? I want that textview does not  to hang out from the top when I'm scrolling listview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="0dp"
    android:id="@+id/info_presents_surveys"
    android:text="@string/info_presents_surveys"
    android:textColor="@color/empty_color"
    android:background="@color/color_gray"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/info_presents_surveys">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view_surveys"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@color/members_speakers.divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Are you trying to make the textview scroll up as well? If so put everything in a Scroll or RecyclerView.

Comment: RecyclerView how do it?

Comment: By the magic of research! That is the whole point and the fun of software development. LEARN! If I tell you exactly how to do this you will never learn. Literally paste RecyclerView into google and I guarantee you will find a plethora of resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TextView` is not within a scrolling component, it's within the parent layout `RelativeLayout` which does not scroll.

In order for it to scroll, you'll have to put it within a `ScrollView` (or similar scrolling component).

So it should be:

```
<ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout>
        <TextView>
        <SwipeRefreshLayout>
             <ListView/>
        </SwipeRefreshLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Type "`ScrollView` tutorial" into Google and it will tell you how.